# api call function issue in Microsoft Edge using angular 2

Tags: angularjs, microsoft-edge

This is the code i used to call my api function:

```
'loadDetail(){
   this.http.get('api/user/getuserdetail/' + this._userid).subscribe(
        data => {
            //..
        }, error => {
            //..
        });
} `
```

This function is fired in a button click (this button is inside a table as a list of row).

Everything's working fine in firefox and chrome. But in Microsoft edge the api function (api/user/getuserdetail) on the server is being fired only if the parameter value (this._userid) changes.  i.e,

case 1: when this._userid = 1, api function is fired;
         when this._userid = 2, api function is fired

but, case 2: when this._userid is again =1, api function on the server is not fired;
 when this._userid = 2, api function not fired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your http call URL to append time stamp like  below :

`api/user/getuserdetail/' + this._userid+"?randomvar="+new Date().getTime();`
this should solve your caching issue of http call